How To Fix Paint Tearout
I recently had ACM (popcorn ceiling) removed from two rooms in my home. During the tear down process the tape that held the containment material to the wall ended up tearing out the paint from the upper part of the walls. So now I’m concerned about the possibility that this wall either has more asbestos (textured drywall/plaster) and/or lead based paint. Is this a DIY type job? Can these spots be covered with some sort of encapsulating material or primer?
Edit To Add: home test kit confirmed lead based paint. Any recommendations on getting this covered and contained?
paint tear out


What year was your home built?  Not all popcorn texture contains asbestos.

for long time China has supplied drywalls with asbestos in it

Home was built in the 40’s. Nothing would surprise me in this house.

the environment is safe to live in if the fibers are sealed in with paint that is in good condition and has not deteriorated over the years.

Lead paint is a hazard for little kids who chew on it. Flat surfaces up high are not dangerous.

@PeteBecker Walls are difficult for kids to chew on. What happens is the paint flakes or turns into dust, which is ingested by kids. The fact that the damaged section has flaked and is likely to flake more makes it a hazard.

It is always possible that a pre-1970s house will have both asbestos and lead paint. The only way to know is to take a sample and send it to a testing lab.
Repairing the tearout is an easy DIY.

Is a home lead testing kit sufficient . Any advice on the repair would be greatly appreciated. Encapsulate? Mud without sanding? Just paint over it?

You have two choices. Either hire a professional. Or, wear a mask, remove loose stuff and paint over it.
Lead paint is not that dangerous unless it is flaking off and gets ingested.
